# If Loop and Row Deleted

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATE:

Situation: I have data that I am trying to consolidate by summing rows based on the first column value (item ID number). If the ID numbers match I want the rows to be added together and the duplicate rows deleted.

I have written the following code and I am experiencing 2 issues: 
1. The first time I run the code there is always a few duplicates left that were not consolidated
2. If I run the code again it sums and deletes rows even if they are not duplicates.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Sub ConsolidateRows()
        Dim WB As Workbook
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim iCol As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastCol As Long
        Dim duplicate As String
        Dim dupRow As Long
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim i As Integer

        'set
        Set WB = Workbooks("Book1")
        Set WS = WB.Sheets("Data")
        LastRow = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        LastCol = WS.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        'Loop to consolidate, delete the duplicate rows
        iRow = 1
        While WS.Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""
            duplicate = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
            iRow = iRow + 1

            For Each cell In WS.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Cells
                    dupRow = cell.Row

            If cell.Value = duplicate And iRow <> dupRow Then
                        For iCol = 3 To LastCol
                                Cells(iRow, iCol) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(dupRow, iCol))
                        Next iCol
                        WS.Rows(dupRow).Delete
                    End If
            Next cell
     Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code and set a `Watch` on the value of `cell.Value` in each case with a breakpoint on the `If` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete rows this way, as the range you are looping will start changing and not refer to the desired cells.  The quickest fix (without totally restructuring the logic) is to add a variable that holds the rows you want to delete, then delete them all after.  My favorite method is using a string with commas as delimiters (easier than using an array)

```
Dim rowsToDelete As String

For Each cell In WS.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
    jRow = cell.Row
       If cell.Value = "Desired Value" Then
           'Do Something
           rowsToDelete = rowsToDelete &  jRow & ","
       End If
Next cell
If Len(rowstoDelete) > 1 Then rowstoDelete = Left(rowsToDelete,Len(rowstoDelete) - 1)

If Len(rowstoDelete) > 0 then
     For i = UBound(Split(rowstoDelete,",")) to 0 Step -1
          WS.Rows(Split(rowstoDelete,",")(i)).Delete
     Next i
End If
```

Comment: Im getting a syntax error on this line:
      For i = UBound(Split(rowstoDelete,",") to 0 Step -1

Comment: @TrackStar2016 forgot a parenthese.  should work now

Comment: I am now getting the error "invalid procedure call or argument" on this line: rowstoDelete = Left(rowstoDelete, Len(rowstoDelete) - 1)

Comment: @TrackStar2016 likely caused by no rows meeting the condition.  Added an if statement to avoid the error

Comment: how would I do that without doing "Exit Sub" there is other things taking place in that sub before and after the loop so I don't want to exit sub

Comment: @TrackStar2016 I've editted the code now so it should work

Comment: This is not working the way I need, I have updated my question and my code to see if I can find a better solution